# Phonegap manage notification when the app is foreground

Tags: push-notification, cordova-plugins, phonegap

i am building mobile application using cordova and phonegap. 
I want to display a popup on device screen when the notification reaches.Is there any plugin in cordova for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/devextremephonegap-how-to-manage-push-notifications-with-fcm/

The 3 events registration, notification and error are managed only if the app is opened.

> **Registration**: the APP registers itself to the push service, receiving
> a unique registrationId. This event is useful if you want to store
> this value to send notifications to single devices;
>
> **Notification**: instead of show the classic notification pop up (depending on the
> phone), the event notication shows a little pop up (using DevExtreme
> feature) to read the message, if the APP is open (if the app is
> closed, you will get the notification in the classic way);
>
> **Error**: if the APP is open and the notification throws some error, here you can manage it.

So, the event you have to mangage is **notification**. This event is raised when a notification is delivered with the app in foreground (so, when the app is running).

Insert this code in the *deviceReady* event:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    android: {
    },
    ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: "true",
        sound: "true",
        clearBadge: "true"
    },
    windows: {}
});
push.on('registration', function (data) {
    // data.registrationId
    DevExpress.ui.notify("Device registered " + data.registrationId, "success", 3000);
});
push.on('notification', function (data) {
    // data.message,
    // data.title,
    // data.count,
    // data.sound,
    // data.image,
    // data.additionalData
    // mostra la notifica se l'app è aperta
    DevExpress.ui.notify(data.message, "info", 10000);
});
push.on('error', function (e) {
    // e.message
    // sarà da togliere, utilissimo in fase di debug
    DevExpress.ui.notify(e.message, "error", 10000);
});
```

and insert the code you need in the notification event. In this case, DevExtreme is used, but if you don't use it you can just show an [alert](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp) or look for what you need (example)[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp).

Comment: Thanks Piero Alberto , so you are saying we cannot do a popup screen when notification receives ?. I know about 'handleNotificationOpened' function to make open call back and 'handleNotificationReceived' only work when app is in foreground. Can i do anything with broadcast plugin in cordova to listen for notification system event.

Comment: You can do a pop up screen only if the app is running when it receveis the notification